# Adding contacts isn't working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been working on a contact app that I'm trying to optimize as much as possible, and for this, it will include a "Add Contact" option, obviously.

There is one problem though, which is that, after trying twice at different times, following this guide didn't work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jjL4R-aiwPE

Apparently it should be working after inserting that code, but I don't know what the difference between his code and mine is.

Here's my code:

```
package com.app.wolfix;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Add_Contact extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name;
    EditText email;
    EditText phone;
    Button addContact;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_contact);

        name = findViewById(R.id.etName);
        email = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        phone = findViewById(R.id.etPhone);
        addContact = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

        addContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!name.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !email.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !phone.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
                        intent.setType(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, name.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, email.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, phone.getText().toString());
                        if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Add_Contact.this, "There is no app that supports this action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Add_Contact.this, "Please fill all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        });
    }
}
```

You can just check the video's conclusion to see how his code is, but here's a sketched screenshot (very poorly made, but I think the essential information is there):
[image: Expectation]

Here's what *I* think is wrong (maybe it could help):

- I'm not doing this in the MainActivity, but rather in a different class, don't know if it has to be forcefully connected to the MainActivity for now;
- the `Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT` and `ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE` parts are different from the final outcome, but both of these and their "counterparts" in the video, which are `Intent.ACTION_INSERT` and `ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE`, respectfully, didn't change anything, so it still didn't work;
- It could also have to do with different Android Studio versions, plugins, variable or class names, but I think this idea seems a little far-fetched.

There's no need to say this, but, just to be sure, the message that appears when trying to add is the error outcome (catch) of the `if()` clause, obviously, which is: **"There is no app that supports this action"**.

Note: if the image of the outcome from the video is missing any information, I'll reupload it. It also doesn't belong to me but rather to the original YouTube channel, Coding Demos, where I was learning to make this class in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app works well on Android 10 and lower, but you use resolveActivity in Android 11 and newer, it always returns null because not add queries in Manifest and to solve the problem you must add queries in Manifest like this

Manifest

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you very much again! That fixed my problem.

Comment: @André_Almeida You are most welcome, please accept the answer

Comment: I already used it, it's working. (I'm not sure what you meant with accepting the answer :/ ).